# WPF Printing - Set the Printer Automataically on WPF PrintDialog

Tags: wpf, printing, flowdocument

I am trying to print a WPF FlowDocument to a particular printer, without prompting the user. The printer is a PDF converter.

This works great except that it prints to the default printer:

```
   PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
   var doc = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource) RTB.Document).DocumentPaginator;
   // I would like to explicitly set the printer to print to here.
   pd.PrintDocument(doc, "Print Document");
```

In WinForms there is a System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings object on document which has a PrinterName property which can be set to the printer I want, but I don't see that in WPF.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You first need a reference in your project to `System.Printing`.  Then you can use the following code right after you declare your `PrintDialog` object.

```
pd.PrintQueue = new PrintQueue(new PrintServer(), "The exact name of my printer");
```

The `PrintQueue` is an object that represents the printer and everything else about that print queue.

Comment: Brilliant! I spent a whole day and couldn't figured it out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: By the way how do you specify a network printer like \\servername\printername

Comment: @Praveena, I'm not sure what the exact syntax is for a network printer.  I always just grab the string from the Print dialog box and use that.

Comment: Hi I got this working  printDlg.PrintQueue = new PrintQueue(new PrintServer(@"\\servername"), "printername"); Your example helped me to think about this.

Comment: @Praveena  Will it work with `(new PrintServer(@"\\server IP")` instead of server name?

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me, when I used a shared network printer:

```
xPrintDialog.PrintQueue = New PrintQueue(New PrintServer("\\computer name"), "printer name")
```